# Solace VMR CLI access automation

Tags: solace

I’m an UNIX Admission and we have a Perl script to login to all of our servers to perform basic health checks. So we would like to add Solace appliances and VMRs to our list. Can we automate this by any chance?

We use “NET:SSH” Perl module in the script. When I pass admin username and password to it, I’m getting “Permission Denied”.

When I try to login with “ssh admin@VPN”, it works fine.

Any clue?

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing read-only health-checks, I recommend you use the SEMP HTTP service to perform health checks remotely as opposed to using SSH to log into each router. Check out the documentation on SEMP [here](https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm)

Comment: Thank you, let me take a look.